# How to create a meta directive in arara?

Tags: arara

I am using `arara` to automatically compile some tikz images as standalone files. I have a bunch of these figures and they all have the same set of directives

```
% arara: clean: { extensions: [ aux, bbl, bcf, blg, out, run.xml ] }
% arara: pdflatex: { options: [ '-halt-on-error' ], interaction: batchmode }
% arara: biber: { options: [ '--validate_datamodel' ] }
% arara: pdflatex: { options: [ '-halt-on-error' ], interaction: batchmode }
% arara: --> until !found('log', 'Rerun to get cross-references right.')
% arara: --> && !found('log', 'There were undefined references.')
% arara: clean: { extensions: [ aux, bbl, bcf, blg, out, run.xml ] }
```

I end up copying these to each image file, but that is a lot of copy and paste and updating if I get something wrong. It is almost a perfect use case for a preamble

```
preambles:
   mytikzimage: |
      % arara: clean: { extensions: [ aux, bbl, bcf, blg, out, run.xml ] }
      % arara: pdflatex: { options: [ '-halt-on-error' ], interaction: batchmode }
      % arara: biber: { options: [ '--validate_datamodel' ] }
      % arara: pdflatex: { options: [ '-halt-on-error' ], interaction: batchmode }
      % arara: --> until !found('log', 'Rerun to get cross-references right.')
      % arara: --> && !found('log', 'There were undefined references.')
      % arara: clean: { extensions: [ aux, bbl, bcf, blg, out, run.xml ] }
```

and calling `arara` with a `-p` switch: `arara -p mytikzimage`, but I want to use a short cut key from my editor which is setup to just call `arara`. What I would like to be able to do is have something like

```
% arara: meta: mytikzimage
```

in the tex file itself that would somehow know about the preamble or some directive that calls all the other directives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a couple of tests and managed to get really close to a viable solution, but at the end of the day, the internal workflow does not allow late directives to be incorporated in the list of tasks to be executed. A hint of what I did:

```
!config
identifier: source
name: Source
commands:
- name: Source file
  command: >
    @{
        import com.github.cereda.arara.utils.DirectiveUtils;
        content = readFromFile(input);
        directives = DirectiveUtils.extractDirectives(content);
        directives = DirectiveUtils.validate(directives);

        /*
           I have a list of all directives from the provided file
           stored in the 'directives' variable, but that is as far
           as one can go...
        */

        return true;
    }
arguments:
- identifier: input
  flag: >
    @{
        return parameters.input;
    }
  required: true
```

I must say this rule is really naughty, as it's using `arara`'s own internal classes to extact directives from the provided file. In this example, I am using an external file, but it could be an explicit list of raw strings or a complex source (like pattern matching of TeX macros, as suggested in another question).

However, I cannot inject this list to the list of directives which was constructed in a previous step. Reflection cannot help me here, and I cannot salvage much what I've done.

A possible improvement is to extend `arara`'s return types and add directive support. That way, a simple `return directives;` statement in this rule would suffice to make `arara` include the newly extracted list of directives to the current execution workflow.

Personally, I think the best solution would be the inclusion of *metadirectives* which would allow early evaluation and decision making. Then I could provide an entire framework to specify such new elements in an easy manner. It does not look too complex, but I must give some thought of common scenarios.

For now, the only solution I can think of is to create a custom rule to invoke `arara` within `arara` and provide the corresponding custom preamble. On the other side of the spectrum, the `files` parameter could be exploited to pass directives to be executed on files other than the current one.

Comment: I may go the call arara from arara route, but will probably just keep cutting and pasting.